# Rewrite {query}.ts to ts.php?{query}

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm not familiar with mod-rewrite, and I could not find any similar questions or solution.
Thank you a lot...

Template:

```
{query1}_{query2}.ts
```

```
ts.php?v={query1}&seg={query2}
```

Example:

```
https://example.com/AAAA-000_2.ts
```

```
https://example.com/ts.php?v=AAAA-000&seg=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples only.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^_]*)_(\d+)\.([\w-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%3.php?v=%1&seg=%2 [NC,L]
```